# Order by slows down query

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
select 
    `gasr`.`RID`,
    `gasr`.`ID`,
    `gr`.`RID`,
    `gr`.`TID`
    ...
from
    (((((((((((( `gasr`
    left join `gasro` ON ((`gasr`.`ID` = `gasro`.`ARID`)))
    left join  `gro` ON ((`gro`.`RID` = `gasr`.`RID`)))
    left join  `p` ON ((`p`.`ID` = `gasr`.`ID`)))
    left join  `l` ON ((`l`.`ID` = `p`.`LID`)))
    left join `k` ON ((`k`.`ID` = `p`.`KID`)))
    left join  `s` ON ((`s`.`ID` = `p`.`TID`)))
    left join  `ad` ON ((`ad`.`ID` = `p`.`DID`)))
    left join  `ae` ON ((`ae`.`ID` = `p`.`EID`)))
    left join  `gr` ON ((`gasr`.`RID` = `gr`.`ID`)))
    left join  `gs` ON ((`gs`.`ID` = `gr`.`SID`)))
    left join `ka` ON ((`ka`.`ID` = `gs`.`KID`)))
    left join `m` ON ((`m`.`ID` = `ka`.`MID`))) 
ORDER BY gs.ID, gr.RID
```

Which does take some time (about 5 seconds) when using the `ORDER BY` as described.
If I will not use `ORDER BY` its really fast (0.08 seconds).

Explain shows me that there will be an temporary table created:
[image]

On both fields of the `order by` part is an normal index (asc).

Is this the problem? How can i avoid this?

TIA 
Matt

Answer (score 1):

*frgtv10, I want to say one word to you, just one word: filesort*

"The Graduate" quotes aside, the fact that you've got keys on both the fields you're sorting by doesn't mean MySQL will be able to use them for sort, and, in this case, it isn't. To quote [MySQL ref's ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html):

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY,…. These cases include the following:
>
> …
>
> - You are joining many tables, and the columns in the ORDER BY are not all from the first nonconstant table that is used to retrieve rows. (This is the first table in the EXPLAIN output that does not have a const join type.)

Now, whether or not this is a true problem depends on the application of your query, specifically whether this specific query is allowed to be slow or not.

Avoiding the issue by getting this `SELECT` + `ORDER` combo up to speed is going to give you a major headache, if it is even possible at all. Personally, in this case, i'd go for sorting the data *after* retrieval if such a thing is possible. Then again, I would recommend against using more than triple or maybe quadruple `JOIN`s in a single query (a [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=mysql%20join%20filesort) will show you that many already hit this issue on a single `JOIN`) and would thus look for a solution that avoids this duodecuple join in its entirety.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is your suggestion then? Do you say just deliver all data and make the filter / order later in PHP?

Comment: As said, it depends on the application and it's need; but yes, based on the info at hand that would be my pick. At the same time, i'd suggest you keep any subset-selection (`WHERE`) in the query, but execute static comparisons before aggregation (i.e. put in on the `JOIN` with an `AND` instead of using a 'late' `WHERE`). Also, depending on the memory footprint of your selection, you may want to get a list by query containing only the order parameters and id's, order it, and then query for additional data.